# Which has a wider reach: app stream_publish or page post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-stream-story

I noticed page feed appears for users if they liked a page before, and the post meets some other factors as explained by FB.

Do these same factors influence app stream_publish as well? Or is that a more effective way of reaching out to the user and their friends?

Comment: You're not comparing like with like, posting to a user or page's feed is something your app does on behalf of that user or the page's admins when they want to use your app to share something, it's not a channel for 'reaching' existing users, it's something your users might use your app for.

Comment: Thanks for this great clarification!